# how to create custom log file using Log4PHP in laravel5.5

Tags: laravel-5.5, log4php

I am using laravel 5.5 and php 7.1.9. How can I create log file using Log4PHP in laravel? I installed Log4php using composer.

Comment: This is my code 
`use Logger;
public function showLogger(){ 
Logger::configure('config.xml');
$log = Logger::getLogger('myLogger');
$log->info("My message."); 
}`         

'aliases' => ['Logger' => Vendor\apache\log4php\src\main\php\Logger::class]

Comment: config.xml `<configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4php/"> 
    <appender name="myConsoleAppender" class="LoggerAppenderConsole" />    
    <appender name="fileappender" class="LoggerAppenderFile"> 
        <layout class="LoggerLayoutPattern">
            <param name="conversionPattern" value="%date{l jS \of F Y h:i:s A}  %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
        <param name="file" value="myLog.log" />
    </appender>
 </configuration>`

Comment: I am getting error ** ErrorException (E_WARNING)
Class 'Vendor\apache\log4php\src\main\php\Logger' not found**